# pre-commit not picking files for pip-tools

Tags: python, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, pip-tools

I've the following repo structure:

```
libs/
- l1/
 - pyproject.toml
- l2/
 - pyproject.toml

batch/
- b1/
 - pyproject.toml
- b2/
 - pyproject.toml

pipelines/
- p1/
 - pyproject.toml
- p2/
 - pyproject.toml

pyproject.toml
```

And the following pre-commit hook configured:

```
---
files: .(yaml|yml|py|toml)$
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools
    rev: 7.3.0
    hooks:
      - id: pip-compile
        name: Run pip-compile for 'prod' env.
        args:
          - -o
          - pyproject.lock
          - --generate-hashes
          - --strip-extras
```

The problem is it only picks the repo root's pyproject.toml file. All the others are skipped? Why is that? I've tried using `files` options to no avail. What is the problem here?

Comment: Could you comment on why you have / need that many distinct _distribution_ packages? What is the contents of all those `pyproject.toml` files?

Comment: @Brian61354270, thanks for the comment - is this relevant for the question? This is an multisite airflow monorepo.

Comment: It is unusual to need many distinct distribution packages. It's even more weird to have a distribution package inside another distribution, since that almost always make it impossible to create portable wheel files. I am just trying to confirm whether having many distributions is actually needed for your use case, or if a simpler approach could work instead (e.g. having one distribution with multiple import packages).

Comment: How are the distributions connected? I'm guessing the "root" distribution lists the sub-projects as `file://` dependencies?

Comment: Nope, your guess is incorrect. `batch` and `pipelines` depends on `libs` being published to some internal pypi.

Comment: I see, thanks. What's the purpose of the top level `pyproject.toml` then? Does it connect the other distributions in any way?

Comment: The purpose of it is define some dependencies atop of which command line tools are built to ease the project management - like building docker images, bumping versions, etc. Having `pyproject.toml` file does not mean at all that something is published or a distribution. This is a way of describing a project and sometimes this is enough and convenient for a number of reasons.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if I am asking about tangents that do not seem relevant. I am just trying to better understand the project layout and your end goal. It's hard to gauge whether this might be an XY problem or not when there aren't many details in the question itself.

Comment: Sure, thanks. Actually I think that there're enough details. As I wrote I just have a monorepo with a couple a python projects and I just want to have locks generated for all of them. I I want to use pip-tools for that and the pre-commit hook they did. For some reason it's not working as I expected. And I try to clarify it here.

Answer (score 0):

there are two separate `files` configurations -- you've overridden the wrong one.

the [`files` at the top level](https://pre-commit.com/#top_level-files) is the whole repository filter -- it's usually used to narrow down to a specific scope if you need it (and uncommon in most uses of `pre-commit`)

the `files` you are trying to overwrite comes originally from the hook itself ([which sets `files: ^requirements\.(in|txt)$`](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/blob/65b0d3672ec737db9d9a9dfef737f88b8344129d/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml#L6)) -- to override that you need to put your `files` inside the hook mapping:

```
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools
    rev: 7.3.0
    hooks:
      - id: pip-compile
        name: Run pip-compile for 'prod' env.
        files: .*requirements*.txt|pyproject.toml$
```

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: Sure, thanks. That's what I've tried. Will do once again.

Comment: Nope, it still processes the file in the root repo and the rest is left untouched.

Comment: you probably need to do a little more to get the output parts working -- I am unfamiliar with this particular hook

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help.